# Package-private member visibility in complex inheritance / package combinations - Qiuck General Rule to verify visibility

Tags: java, inheritance, visibility, protected, package-private

If Base and Derived classes are in different packages then *package-private member* from *Base* shall not be inherited and thus it shall be absent in *Derived*, that is such member shall be inaccessible both thru `Base obj = new Derived()` and `Derived obj = new Derived()` -`obj.member()` shall give a compile error in either case!

But I see that for `Base obj = new Derived()`, `obj.f()` is accessible!

Yes, private members are still there because when I create `new Derived()` then `new Base()` is also created with all its private members (under the hood). But if I change *package-private* `f()` in code below to *private*, `obj.f()` would be compile error for `Base obj = new Derived()`, as expected... *Anyway, I suspect that in my example with package-private members, it is exactly like this - having access from Derived class to (implicitly existing) private (-)  members of its superclass (Base class).*

(-) (because Base and Derived are in different packages)

```
package com.main_pkg;

public class Base {     
    void f() { } // default visibility        
}
```

and

```
package org.another_pkg;

import com.main_pkg.Base;

public class Derived extends Base {         

}
```

and

```
package com.totally.different_pkg;

import org.another_pkg.Derived;

public class DerivedFromDerived extends Derived {

}
```

finally

```
import org.another_pkg.Derived;

import com.totally.different_pkg.DerivedFromDerived;

public class Driver {  // Base class is in same pkg as Driver!

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Base obj1 = new Derived();
        obj1.f(); // f() is visible!

        Base obj2 = new DerivedFromDerived();
        obj2.f();  // f() is visible!
    }
}
```

Could you please **formulate a quick-and-easy practical rule** (in other words than in JLS and common-place default-visibility definitions) how **to understand visibility (access) in complex inheritance / package combinations**(we might have complex hierarchy Base->Derived->Derived2->Derived3 and every class(es) can be in same/different packages. How to quess accessibility quick?

For example, for a *protected* member (of Base class) the "quick-guess" rule is very simple:

1. if *Base and Driver are in same package* (that is from any Driver's
   method the code `Base obj = new Base(); obj.baseProtectedMember();`
   compiles) => any combination would work (Base obj1 = new Derived2();
   Derived2 obj2 = new Derived2(), etc - `obj1.baseProtectedMember()`
   and `obj2.baseProtectedMember()` are visible and can be called). *And we do not care in what packages other classes are!*
2. *if Base and Driver are NOT in same package* (that is from any Driver's
       method the code `Base obj = new Base(); obj.baseProtectedMember();`
       DOES NOT compile) => any combination (see 1) would NOT work. *And we do not care in what packages other classes are!*

But for package-private members we *do care about in which package which hierarchy class is*, and I cannot formulate an easy and reliable "quick-guess" rule for the general case...

P.S. *Interesting SIDE-NOTE:*

If I override methods in Derived and DerivedFromDerived (leaving them package-private) in the code-snippet above (at the top of the post), the output is:

```
f() from Base called
f() from Base called
```

Comment: The quick and easy rule is: package private members are visible in the package where they are defined.

Comment: "shall not be inherited" they are inherited, they just aren't visible.

Answer (score 1):

`Base` and `Driver` are in the same package, so `Driver` can see `Base`'s package private methods. If you declared `Base obj1 = new Derived()` as `Derived obj1 = new Derived()` you would not see `f()`. The same holds true for `Base obj2 = new DerivedFromDerived()`, in that if you declared it as a `DerivedFromDerived`, you would not see `f()`.